# angular 4 routing issue.when navigating next route previous view also displaying

Tags: angular, routes

I have route like this,

->user select all the three dropdown and click on search it should navigate /searchdetails and display respective component.

->routing works fine .when navigating searchdetails, previous view also displaying like this :attached image link and screenshot you can a have look at that.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKTW0.jpg

[image]

app.component.ts

```
this.searchService.getSearchbyDistrictCategoryCity(this.searchObj).subscribe(data=>{
    this.searchedResults = data;
    this.searchService.searchResults = data; 
    console.log(this.searchedResults);
    this.router.navigate(['/searchdetails'])
  },error=>this.errorMessage= <any>error);
```

app-routing.module.ts.

```
const appRoutes:Routes = [

   {path:'searchdetails',component:SearcheddetailsComponent}
];
```

Comment: There must be error while rendering next view

Comment: @HarshalPatil no error in console

Comment: @Ajay any luck? Seeing a similiar issue myself

Comment: try to run following code within ngZone.run(()=>{ }), I am facing the same issue because I try to run code outside the angular scope.